# create-react-app based projects added font but not working

Tags: reactjs, fonts, font-face

I'm using create-react-app and prefer not to eject.
i imported in index.html file . and give it default font. but its not working.

```
<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Gumela;
            src: url("../src/fonts/*");
        }
        * {
            font-family: "Gumela";
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert font-face on your App.css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Gumela;
  src: url('./fonts/Gumela\ Regular.otf');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the fonts in your app.css or index.css file.

And try:

```
 @font-face {
            font-family: Gumela;
            src: url("../src/fonts/*");
            font-display: swap; // This will swap font once its loaded, for SEO purpose.
        }


* {
    font-family: Gumela;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;

    OR

    font: Gumela normal 20px;
  }
```

Comment: i tryed but not working....

Comment: Are you sure you had the right location of the font in the URL? 
Can you share the location of the font and the file name of the font?

Comment: yes.  font C:\Users\user\Desktop\react my practise\protfolio0.1\src\fonts\Gumela Regular.otf

Comment: Try this as your font source src: url(./src/fonts/Gumela Regular.otf); >>>>> This is in App.css file.

Comment: tried but steel not working

Comment: src: url(./src/fonts/GumelaRegular.otf); >> Remove the space between Gumela and Regular in the css and on the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I imported the font here: https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/00561b492d88a5287a5def1e83a34882 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

just add this in head before your style tag.

`<link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/00561b492d88a5287a5def1e83a34882?family=Gumela" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`